# Sending a request from other country without using a VPN / manual testing

Tags: performance, request, performance-testing, manual-testing

I have to test the performance of picture uploading from USA without using a VPN on WEB and on iOS device. Will be good if at least I could sent a request from to USA. Is it possible ? There is any app which can help me?

I try BrowserStack but it's not what I expect,

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to upload something without a VPN established, you could -

Get a VPS in the region you would like to test (the US in your case), then connect over a remote desktop, it could be either RDP or VNC. With that, you could open a browser in the VPS and do everything you want just like a local machine.

But this is only for Web case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do local based testing using BrowserStack you can do that using the geolocation feature it offers, but for that you would need to be on enterprise plan.
Link- [https://www.browserstack.com/docs/ip-geolocation#:~:text=BrowserStack's%20IP%20Geolocation%20feature%20allows,30%2B%20states%20around%20the%20world](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/ip-geolocation#:%7E:text=BrowserStack%27s%20IP%20Geolocation%20feature%20allows,30%2B%20states%20around%20the%20world).

Other way is you can use BrowserStack GPS location feature for the same.
Link- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/test-real-user-conditions/simulate-gps-location

For testing app performance you can use this - https://www.browserstack.com/app-performance
Link- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-performance/overview/what-is-browserstack-app-performance

I hope this helps.